# Mathematica - Solving for the input of a taylor series such that coefficients are minimized

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, solver, taylor-series

I need to find the value of a variable s such that the taylor expansion of an expression involving s:

1. Has a minimum (preferably zero, but due to binary minimum is sufficient) in as many coefficients other than 0th order as possible (preferably more than that one minimum coefficient, but 2nd and 3rd have priority).
2. reports the best n values of s that fulfill the condition within the region (ie show me the 3 best values of s and what the coefficients look like for each).

I have no idea how to even get the output of a `Series[]` command into any other mathematica command without receiving an error, much less how to actually solve the problem. The equation I am working with is too complex to post here (multi-regional but continuous polynomial expression that can be expanded). Does anyone know what commands to use for this?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should realize is that the output of `Series` is not a sum but a a `SeriesData` object. To convert it into a sum you have to wrap it in `Normal[Series[...]]`. Since the question doesn't provide details, I can't say more.